# WTSRegisterSessionNotification doesn't work sometimes on startup with XP home

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, startup

I'm using the function/message to check if the workstation is locked. Now my application is in the startup folder. It has worked without any problems on XP pro, but since I'm using the program on XP home WTSRegisterSessionNotification fails about 50% of the time on startup, but it never fails when the system is already booted up. Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On XP, services start in the background and do not block boot or logon.  The termsrv service is most likely not running by the time you call WTSRegisterSessionNotification.

You can check if the service is running by:

```
// Error handling omitted for brevity
SC_HANDLE scm = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, GENERIC_READ);
SC_HANDLE svc = OpenService(scm, L"TermSrv", SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
SERVICE_STATUS status;
QueryServiceStatus(svc, &status);
if (status.dwCurrentSTate != SERVICE_RUNNING) {
    // Try to start, wait and try again, etc.
}

CloseServiceHandle(svc);
CloseServiceHandle(scm);
```

Comment: Should probably be "TermService" instead of "TermSrv".

Answer (score 3):

Reading from the MSDN remarks section for  [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(VS.85).aspx)  it says

> If this function is called before the dependent services of Terminal Services have started, an `RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING` error code may be returned. When the Global\TermSrvReadyEvent global event is set, all dependent services have started and this function can be successfully called.

So a neat solution might be to use [OpenEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684305(VS.85).aspx) to obtain a handle to the `Global\TermSrvReadyEvent` event then use  [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx)  (with the handle obtained from `OpenEvent` and a sensible timeout) to wait for the terminal services to start (causing the handle to be signalled) before calling `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`.

Of course, you could probably also call `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` to begin with then, if it fails, use `GetLastError` to see if it returned `RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING` and if so, do the above.

Comment: Ah... thanks to both of you. I suspected XP home being the cause of the failure. It was just an accident then...

Cheers